# Get JSON Data with PHP cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a simple script that outputs some JSON. I'm trying to retrieve the JSON contents in a variable with another PHP script, but when I do a var_dump(), I'm getting NULL instead of the JSON data.

Here's the JSON. The only output is: `{"ProductID":"1000096","ProductStyleID":"1001029","ProductCategoryID":"1000004"}`

### json.php

```
$arr['ProductID'] = "1000096";
$arr['ProductStyleID'] = "1001029";
$arr['ProductCategoryID'] = "1000004";

$json_arr = json_encode($arr);
echo $json_arr;
```

And here's the cURL script, which right now is outputting NULL:

### curl.php

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "/json.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

How can I retrieve the JSON echoed in the json.php script?

Comment: provide full path instead of `"/json.php"`

Comment: Well, that was fast. Didn't know I had to use the full URL as I'm used to using partial paths instead. Thanks a lot, guys. :)

Comment: @GTSJoe  glad to help you.:):)

Comment: curl runs on the server. it has NO idea what your browser is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see a basic CURL example:- http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

You come to know that instead of:-

`"/json.php"`

You need to give full path like:-

(http://...) or (https://...)  for your file (based on your server)

*Note:- Rest of your code seems perfectly fine.Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

This is the URL to get the data:-

```
$url="https://.../api.php?action";
```

Using cURL:

```
//  Initiate curl
$cuh = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($cuh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($cuh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($cuh, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($cuh);
// Closing
curl_close($cuh);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Comment: not really helpful to OP. far away from actual answer